# question on orthogonal polynomials and space spanned by them

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, inner-products, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

Consider the space of real polynomials on $[0,1]$ with scalar product $\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx$. Let $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ be a set of  pairwise orthogonal polynomials.

Assume that $f$ and $g$ satisfy:

- $\langle f,g\rangle=0$,
- $\deg f=\deg g$,
- $f(t)=g(t)$ for some $t\in[0,1]$,
- $span\{f_1,\dots,f_n,f\}=span\{f_1,\dots,f_n,g\}$.

Does it imply $f=g$ ?

Comment: If $f = g$ then necessarily $f = g = 0$ because $f \perp g$.